# Has Dragon Ball Super Broly changed the original Dragon Ball story?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the new upcoming movie Dragon Ball Super movie it doesnt seem Goku is the same age than it was when Grandpa Gohan found him in the anime series. Plus he wasnt using an armor in the anime. Some people around say this was anime filler and that those events of the anime werent told in the Dragon Ball manga (something I ignore). Has Dragon Ball Super Broly changed the story of the original Dragon Ball story, or simply what we see now in the Dragon Ball movie Broly trailer is different than in the anime because those scenes from the original anime were filler?

Comment: As far as I remember, Goku was born in April of year 737, the same time as Broly meanwhile Vegeta is said to be born in year 732. The Tournament of Power takes place in year 780. They might be doing this to make both Vegeta and Goku stay in their primes for a longer time before aging them out of relevance.

Answer (score 1):

The scenes in original anime were filler added by **Toei Animation**. So the new story does not contradict the original manga written by **Akira Toriyama**. Also Toriyama had released a manga called **Dragon Ball Minus** which is the story upto Goku being sent to Earth. In this manga, Goku is shown wearing a saiyan armor and is 3 years old. As the **Dragon Ball Super Broly** movie is written by Toriyama, the same details are included in the movie as the manga.

As the anime was dependent on the manga, Toei Animation had to add many fillers to make sure the manga was ahead of the anime. Hence the discrepancy.